# How do I use the output of a macro to get multiple arguments for another macro?

Tags: macros

The following is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{bla}{{blu1}{blu2}}{{error}{schmerror}}
}

\newcommand{\switch}[2]{#2 #1}

\begin{document}

\test{bla} % this works

\switch12 % this works

\switch\test{bla} \\

\expandafter\switch\test{bla}

\expandafter\switch\expandafter{\test{bla}}

\switch{\test{bla}}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

I'm trying to get the `\switch` macro to take the output of `\test{bla}` as argument, returning blu2 blu2. But not even `\expendafter` does the trick. Is there any way to get something like this to work?

The first two lines just make sure that both commands work as expected.

My first attempt, `\switch\text{bla}`, obviously swaps `\test` and `{bla}` resulting in `bla errorschmerror` since the argument of `\test` isn't `bla`. (I think it's the `\par` token, since the next attempt outputs on the same line if I leave out `\\`.)

My second attempt, `\expandafter\switch\test{bla}`, just returns bla. As far as I can tell, `\test` simply gets replaced by nothing on expansion, and \switch switches `{bla}` with something (no idea what though). At first I wondered whether this was due to `\ifstrequal` not being expandable, which might somehow result in `\test` expanding to , but then the next attempt should show the same behavior.

However, my third attempt obviously does replace `\test{bla}` with `{blu1blu2}` on expansion. This then gets switched with something by `\switch`. This isn't what I intend though, I want `\switch`to operate on two arguments, `{blu1}` and `{blu2}`, which should both be provided by `\test`.

The fourth attempt seems to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: ifstrequal doesn't work by expansion so you need to change the syntax of your calls, or use a different equality test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `\expandafter\switch\test{bla}`

is

```
\switch\ifstrequal{blah}{bla}{{blu1}{blu2}}{{error}{schmerror}}
```

which is

```
blah \ifstrequal {bla}{{blu1}{blu2}}{{error}{schmerror}}
```

which is not what you want.

You could change the call structure to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\test}[2]{%
\ifstrequal{#2}{bla}{#1{blu1}{blu2}}{#1{error}{schmerror}}%
}

\newcommand{\switch}[2]{#2 #1}

\begin{document}

\test{}{bla}

\test\switch{bla} 

\end{document}
```